# Weird blueish line on texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm trying to put an image texture on this object but every time this line appears

[image: I tried to move the points where it starts and where it finish but don't want to dissapear]

[image]

[image]

Here it is the file too: [image]

And the texture image: [image]

Comment: This line is not black. Its blueish, i guess from the texture. Did you UV-unwrap your model?

Comment: please provide blend file because you nearly posted no useful information, thx

Comment: Hi, Letz.. welcome to BSE.. could you please edit to augment this question with an image of your UV Map, and 'wireframe' switched on for your object, so we can see its topology. That might provide us with enough information to answer.

Comment: Sure but i don't know much can help the UV map because its an image.

Comment: taiyo actually i didn't i just projected from view because if i unwrap it i will unable to put this texture, there is any method to unwrap it and put this texture? Sorry but i'm new in blender :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have severly messed up uv coordinates, see the overlapping triangles in the screenshot. I am not even sure how you achieved this with projecting from view. If you set the interpolation mode on the texture to `Closest`, you can see better how the texels are strongly distorted.

[image]

UV unwrapping is a complex topic, but you could start with this:

- head over to the `UV Editing` tab
- in the 3d viewport, go to edit mode, select everything and do `UV > Smart UV Project` and `OK` (there are other options, but this one is good for a start)
- you should have 4 uv islands now in the UV editor. Three are connected: the blade sides and the top of the blade. The jags are a bunch of chaos (for manually making better islands, checkout how to make [seams](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/unwrapping/seams.html)). If you translate/scale/rotate the blade side uv's now to map the sword in the image, it should look correct. You can select an island for example with selecting one uv-vertex and then holding arrow up (or `Ctrl Numpad +` if you are using Blender style controls).

The image has no high resolution anyway, but the texels are not distorted anymore.

[image]